# dragging a image in boundary

Tags: android, touch, drag

[image]

I want that image only be dragged in its parent view. when user tries to drag it outside the view it will return its original position. basically i'm implementing android unlock type feature. please help me out. Its my main class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
  }

  private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
      //int action = event.getAction();
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // Do nothing
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);
        setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        owner.removeView(view);
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
        container.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:         
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);
      default:
        break;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topleft"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"       
    android:background="@drawable/shape" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and the problem is....?

Comment: i want to drag it horizontally only. when user drag it up or down drag and touch event should be cancel.and image should return its original position.

Comment: have you done this ? if yes please share the answer

Comment: @contactmeandroid sorry i dont have solution. i didnt tried it further. if you get solution share it here.

Comment: Did you find the solution of this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive the movement control by using this in OnTouch() method.

```
//Some global variables
    float oldX=0,oldY=0;
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        oldY=motionEvent.getY();
        oldX=motionEvent.getX();
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
       } else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if((motionEvent.getY()>oldY+10 || motionEvent.getY()<oldY-10))//The value 10 is controlling sensitivtiy of y axis greater than 10 or less than 10 the below code will be fired.
          {
             view.setEnabled(false);
                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)            view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = oldX;
            layoutParams.topMargin = oldY;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setEnabled(true);
          }
      }
      }
```